# Cassandra READ Where In performance

Tags: cassandra, storage

I have a Cassandra cluster of 6 nodes, each one has 96 CPU/800 RAM.

My table for performance tests is:

```
create table if not exists space.table
(
    id          bigint primary key,
    data        frozen<list<float>>,
    updated_at  timestamp
);
```

Table contains 150.000.000 rows.

When I was testing it with query:

```
SELECT * FROM space.table WHERE id = X
```

I even wasn't able to overload cluster, the client was overloaded by itself, RPS to cluster were 350.000.

Now I'm testing a second test case:

```
SELECT * FROM space.table WHERE id in (X1, X2 ... X3000)
```

I want to get 3000 random rows from Cassandra per request.

Max RPS in this case **15 RPS** after that occurs a lot of pending tasks in Cassandra thread pool with type: **Native-Transport-Requests**.
Isn't it the best idea to get big resultsets from cassandra? What is the best practice, for sure I can divide 3000 rows to separate requests, for example 30 request each with 100 ids.
Where can I find info about it, maybe WHERE IN operation is not good from performance perspective?

Update:

Want to share my measurements for getting 3000 rows by different chunk size from Cassandra:

> ```
> Test with 3000 ids per request
>
> Latency: 5 seconds
> Max RPS to cassandra: 20
>
>
> Test with 100 ids per request (total 300 request each by 100 ids)
> Latency at 350 rps to service (350 * 30 = 10500 requests to cassandra): 170 ms (q99), 95 ms (q90), 75 ms(q50)
> Max RPS to cassandra: 350 * 30 = 10500
>
> Test with 20 ids per request (total 150 request each by 20 ids) 
> Latency at 250 rps to service(250 * 150 = 37500 requests to cassandra): 49 ms (q99), 46 ms (q90), 32 ms(q50)
> Latency at 600 rps to service(600 * 150 = 90000 requests to cassandra): 190 ms (q99), 180 ms (q90), 148 ms(q50)
> Max RPS to cassandra: 650  * 150 = 97500
>
>
> Test with 10 ids per request (total 300 request each by 10 ids)
> Latency at 250 rps to service(250 * 300 = 75000 requests to cassandra): 48 ms (q99), 31 ms (q90), 11 ms(q50)
> Latency at 600 rps to service(600 * 300 = 180000 requests to cassandra): 159 ms (q99), 95 ms (q90), 75 ms(q50)
> Max RPS to cassandra: 650  * 300 = 195000
>
>
> Test with 5 ids per request (total 600 request each by 5 ids)
> Latency at 550 rps to service(550 * 600 = 330000 requests to cassandra): 97 ms (q99), 92 ms (q90), 60 ms(q50)
> Max RPS to cassandra: 550  * 660 = 363000
>
>
> Test with 1 ids per request (total 3000 request each by 1 ids)
> Latency at 190 rps to service(250 * 3000 = 750000 requests to cassandra): 49 ms (q99), 43 ms (q90), 30 ms(q50)
> Max RPS to cassandra: 190  * 3000 = 570000
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IN` is really not recommended to use, especially for so many individual partition keys.  The problem is that when you send query with `IN`:

1. query sent to the any node (coordinator node), not necessary node that is owning the data
2. then that coordinator node identifies which nodes are owning data for specific partition keys
3. queries are sent to identified nodes
4. coordinator node collects results from all nodes
5. result is consolidated and sent back

This puts a lot of load onto the coordinator node, and making the whole query as slow as the slowest node in the cluster.

The better solution would be to use prepared queries and sent individual async requests for each of partition keys, and then collect data in your application.  Just take into account that there are limits on how many in-flight queries could be per connection.

P.S. It should be possible to optimize that further, by looking into your values, finding if different partition keys are in the same token range, generate the `IN` query for all keys in the same token range, and send that query setting the routing key explicitly.  But it requires more advanced coding.